# {{}} not rendering data from the controller

Tags: angularjs

Seek your help with this. Where am i going wrong?

This is my html:

```
    <div data-ng-controller="documentPreviewCtrl">
        <h1> Header {{testHeader}} </h1>
         <div id="bodyContent">
            {{testData}}
            {{data}}
         </div>
      </div>
```

This is my js.

```
    documentPreview.controller('documentPreviewCtrl',['$scope','$element',function($scope,$element)     {
$scope.initView($element);
$scope.$on('showPreview',function(event, data){
    alert(data+ " clicked!");
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.testHeader = "This is the header";
    $scope.testData = "This is just some dummy data.";
}); 
}]);
```

But my html just shows: 'Header'. Why does it not read the data inside {{testHeader}} or {{testData}}. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Comment: What's the initView function? It's a bit unusual to use $element in a controller... why do you need it here? Can you setup a plunker?

Comment: Why are you listening to `showPreview` event on the scope before setting the data? Who is emitting that event?

Comment: Well, am new to AngularJS and the html design handed down to me is quite complex. To elaborate at best, there is a main (html) page which has some clickable icons. Depending on which icon is clicked, data needs to be pulled in and displayed into my html page. So when an icon is clicked on the main page, am generating a 'showPreview' broadcast which is read by my controller and upon receiving this broadcast and the info on the item clicked (that is data), my idea is to pull up the data. Am unable to think up a better workable approach at this point with my limited knowledge of angular.

Comment: The idea of using initView is to render some html stuff when the page loads. In the meanwhile working on setting up something in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

from the comments it seems you should start with this

```
documentPre.controller('documentPreviewCtrl',['$scope','$element',function($scope,$element)     {
    $scope.initView($element);
    $scope.testHeader = "This is the header";
    $scope.testData = "This is just some dummy data.";
}]);
```

then whenever you click something append the data by the onclick func like this

```
<div data-ng-controller="documentPreviewCtrl">
        <h1 ng-click="headerClick"> Header {{testHeader}} </h1>
         <div id="bodyContent" style="display:none">
            {{testData}}
            {{data}}
         </div>
      </div>
```

and now your CTRL should look like this

```
documentPre.controller('documentPreviewCtrl',['$scope','$element',function($scope,$element)     {
    $scope.initView($element);
    $scope.headerClick = function(data){
        //notice that data can be your scope item
        $scope.testHeader = "This is the header";
        $scope.testData = "This is just some dummy data.";
    };
}]);
```

after you get this working i have a mini tutorial about broadcasting:
http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/angularjs-and-ajax-angular-is-not.html

EDIT:
another thing is to remember that angular is not turn-base like standard JS programming, so it can be that your event that you broadcasted didnt happened where it should and the Digest() missed it. a nice solution is to use $timeout that is always rendered last.

the right solution is an architectural one, which is that all your data is stored in a service and the view is reading from the service only, and the CTRL is just the one telling the service what was clicked. see here for a detailed tutorial:http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/breslevelopers-angularjs-tutorial.html

Comment: Well thank you but this is still not working. From what i could infer so far the data initialization that am trying to do upon receiving the   broadcast is not read during the html rendering as expected. Wish the angularjs docs would explain more on how the $on and $broadcast work in terms of data loading. 

Because if am using $scope.data outside of $scope.$on(....), {{data}} is read fine in the html.

Comment: hi, please see my EDIT in the post

Comment: Am new to 'Stackoverflow' as well :-/ .Tried voting, says it requires '15 reputation'; guess i got just 1.